# Using MySQL CHECK to make sure value in table matches in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I want to have one of my tables check to make sure that values entered into one of its fields are correct.

In my case, I have a table called Book, and a table called Sale. Since each sale has the isbn of a book, it should be possible for me to make sure that the price entered into the Sale table matches the price that corresponds to the isbn in the Book table. I'm convinced that I ought to be using the CHECK constraint in SQL, but I do not know how to go about doing this.

Parent Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Book
(
    isbn INTEGER NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(20),
    author VARCHAR(20),
    price DOUBLE,
    PRIMARY KEY (isbn)
);
```

An INSERT into the Book table:

```
INSERT INTO Book
VALUES (1, 'A Separate Peace', 'John Knowles' 9.99);
```

My Child Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Sale
(
    date DATE,
    saleId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    isbn INTEGER,
    price DOUBLE,
    PRIMARY KEY (saleId),
    FOREIGN KEY (isbn) REFERENCES Book (isbn),
    CHECK (price = (Book (price) WHERE Book (isbn) = isbn))
);
```

Example INSERT statement for Sale:

```
INSERT INTO Sale 
VALUES ('2012-01-01', 1234, 1, 8.99);
```

Notice that the correct price is 9.99, not 8.99. I want this INSERT to return an error.

Comment: MySQL does not enforce `CHECK` constraints. You would need a composite column foreign key.

Comment: @Martin Smith - But according to this tutorial http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp MySQL uses at least some kind of CHECK. But is there any way around this if I can't use CHECK? or do I simply have to make sure that my code inserts correct data?

Comment: It parses the syntax for compatibility reasons but doesn't enforce it. Actually a FK would be no good either as I was wondering why you were denormalizing and see this is for historic sales. The FK would not allow you to adjust the price of the book in the future.

Comment: @Martin Smith - I'm practicing using FK right now. I'm pretty new to SQL - just had my first MySQL installed the past week. I am trying to create this table to hook up to a Java application, which would ideally get live sales from user input. But am I using FK wrong for that purpose as well??

Comment: Just to be clear your current use of the FK is fine but it wouldn't be suitable to extend this to `isbn,price` in order to enforce this.

Comment: @user1079776: What Martin means (I assume) is that `Book.price` is/should be storing the book's current price, which can be chganging in time. The `Sale.price` is/should be storing the price that the book was sold (and thus never change).

Comment: @ypercube - Yes that's what I meant. Thanks for phrasing it intelligibly!

Comment: @user1079776: MySQL does **not** use `CHECK`. It parses the check definition and **silently ignores** it.

Comment: @ypercube Exactly. From the MySQL documentation: The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement this kind of business logic in the software part of the system.

- How about when you would like to offer a discount or when a product is on offers?
- What if a sale lets say 1 year before for Book1 was 9.99 and a year later the price for the same book changes to 8.99?

If you don't want that, then there is no reason for saving the price twice (in both tables), therefore just remove the price column from Sales table, and use the isbn no when reading from the database to determine the price of the product.

Comment: Ahhh, you are right. That would complicate things. So this is something that I would have to manage before I even arrive at a Data Access Object.

Comment: But either way, is it still impossible to accomplish what I'm trying to do strictly in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that prices can change and you want to have the current book prices in `Book.price`, while the prices that books are sold in `Sale.price`.

To ensure that the price inserted into table `Sale` is the current book price (stored in `Book`), instead of:

```
INSERT INTO Sale 
  VALUES ('2012-01-01', 1234, 1, 8.99) ;
```

you could use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Sale 
  SELECT '2012-01-01', 1234, isbn, price
  FROM Book
  WHERE isbn = 1 ;
```

Comment: That's an awesome way to do it. I like how it ensures that the price is ensured, without the need to create any constraints or foreign keys. Although it does create duplicate data, as for now, I am simply satisfied with the fact that I've learned a new way to write a DML statement.

Comment: If the prices never change, then you don't really need the `price` in table `Sale`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes @ypercube 's solution will achieve what you want, BUT that goes against best practices and [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

If that was the case then we should also add more columns in the sales table for the name, author etc.

I suggest that you separate the business logic and keep it simple unless you really have to.

Comment: Why is it against normalization?

Comment: If the price in sales is ALWAYS the same as the one in the books table, then it would be like keeping duplicate values. If the logic is only in the insert statement like your answer, i guess it could be accepted.

Comment: Ah, ok then. I assumed that prices can change :)